# Why does $E = 0$ inside conducting sphere?

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law, conductors

Given this picture, I've understood that giver r>R, E = q/(4πεR^2) but I just can't get why inside the sphere, E equals 0? And the notes don't explain something. I've tried to look it up on the web and found similar examples that don't explain it either...

[image]

Comment: For the exact same reason there is no gravity inside the Earth.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inside a conductor?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/100474/)

Comment: 0celo7: the only place inside the Earth where the gravity is zero is at the centre. By contrast the field is zero **everywhere** inside a conductor.

Comment: @JohnRennie: I should have said hollow sphere, correct? My bad.

Comment: @0celo7: well yes, there is no gravity inside a hollow shell, but the OP is asking about a solid conductor not a hollow one (or at least they don't specifically say it's hollow).

Comment: @JohnRennie: Doesn't a spherical conductor have the charge on the surface, just like a shell has the mass on the shell?

Comment: @0celo7: yes, and qud's answer (now deleted) pointed that out. But I think you should deduce that fact not assume it. The obvious answer is the one Alfred has just given - the field has to be zero because if it was non-zero the conduction electrons would simply move until it was.

Answer (score 0):

First, the context is [electrostatics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatics) so we assume the net force on any charged particle is *zero*; if the net force is not zero, the charged particle will accelerate and the situation would not be static.

Inside a [conductor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_conductor), by definition, charge is free to move; *if* there is an electric field inside, charge will be *accelerated*.

Thus, we must conclude that, *in the electrostatic case*, there is no electric field inside a conductor.

Put another way, if there is an electric field inside, it is not the electrostatic case.