# Gauss law in an unconventional conducting body

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, conductors, coulombs-law

Suppose we have a spherical conductor the electric field aroud in $\sigma/e$ around it now we remove a small part dq away the electric field around it will now remain $\sigma/e$ as the $e$ due to $dq$ has vaniished
Now does the electric field inside the conductor remains zero? the solution to the problem is that no since the symmetry is lost and now interior has $\sigma /2e$ just below the sphere part removed!
But isnt the electric field inside a conductor zero.
what conclusion do we get from here?

[image]

Comment: Electric field inside _closed_ conductor is zero. This is not a closed conductor. Topologically, your "slightly open" sphere is no different than a plate...

Comment: @Floris will unsymmetrical conductors like for eg a dumbbell shape have xzero field i have this doubt because in $integral E.ds$  since E has no symmetry from r we cant remove from integral to apply gauss law

Comment: If the conductor is closed the field inside is zero. If the field was not zero, it would exert a force on the charges on the surface - and they would move until the field is zero. See for example [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/100485/26969)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume the removed part to be conducting plate and for any conducting body the field outside is $$\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_{0}}$$ so hence for big sphere (without removing the part)The field from each surface point would cancel out each other diametrically opposite hence there was no field inside.But now the point opposite to the hole produces a field towards the opposite point.